# fastify-http-proxy: Swagger is flooded with prefix URL REST methods

Tags: swagger, http-proxy, fastify

I am trying out to write the swagger using fastify and fastify-swagger in localhost. However my real server is running somewhere else which has the backend logic. I am trying to proxy my localhost API call to the remote upstream using fastify-http-proxy.

So in essence, the swagger I want to serve from localhost and and all the actual API call I want to proxy to remote upstream.

My fastify-http-proxy configuration:

```js
fastify.register(require('fastify-http-proxy'), {
    upstream: "https://mystaging.com/notifications",
    prefix: '/notifications',
    replyOptions: {
        rewriteRequestHeaders: (originalRequest, headers) => {
            return {
                ...headers,
            };
        },
    },
    async preHandler (request, reply) {
        console.log('Request URL: ', request.url);
        if (request?.url?.includes('api-docs')) {
            console.log('Request contains api-docs. Ignore the request...');
            return;
        }
    },
});
```

Basically my intention is that any upcoming request coming to `http://127.0.0.1:8092/notifications` should be proxied to and served by the `https://mystaging.com/notifications`. E.g. `POST http://127.0.0.1:8092/notifications/agent-notifications` should be actually forwarded to `https://mystaging.com/notifications/agent-notification`. That's why I configured the fastify-http-proxy as the above way.

My fastify-swagger configuration:

```js
fastify.register(require('fastify-swagger'), swaggerConfig);

const swaggerConfig = {
    openapi: {
      info: {
        title: `foo bar`,
        description: `API forwarded for notifications service`,
        version: '1.0.0'
      },
      servers: [
        { url: `${server}` },
      ],
      tags: [
        { name: 'notifications', description: "Notifications"},
      ],
      components: {
        securitySchemes: {
          authorization: {
            type: 'http',
            scheme: 'bearer',
            bearerFormat: 'JWT',
            description: 'JWT access token to authorize the request, sent on the request header.'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    exposeRoute: true,
    routePrefix: `localhost:8092/notifications/external/api-docs`,
};
```

Once I opened the swagger in the browser using URL http://localhost:8092/notifications/external/api-docs/static/index.html, I am seeing other than the notifications tag, there are very REST verb of /notifications/ is coming up as the attached picture.

Once I turn of the fastify-http-proxy, everything works fine.

What am I missing/messing up here.

Screenshot of spurious default routes:

[image]

Versions used:

```json
    "fastify": "^3.21.6",
    "fastify-auth0-verify": "^0.5.2",
    "fastify-swagger": "^4.8.4",
    "fastify-cors": "^6.0.2",
    "fastify-http-proxy": "^6.2.1",
```

Notes added further:

The route specification looks like:

```js
module.exports = async function (fastify, opts) {
    fastify.route({
        method: 'POST',
        url: `${url}/agent-notifications`,
        schema: {
            description: 'Something',
            tags: ['notifications'],
            params:{
                $ref: 'agent-notifications-proxy-request#',
            },
        },
        handler: async (request, reply) => {
        }
    });
}
```

And here is the `agent-notifications-proxy-request`:

```js
module.exports = function (fastify) {
    fastify.addSchema({
        $id: 'agent-notifications-proxy-request',
        title: "AgentNotificationRequest",
        description:'Trying out',
        type: 'object',
        example: 'Just pass the same stuff as-is',
        properties: {
            'accountId': {
                type: 'string'
            },
            'templateName': {
                type: 'string'
            },
            "bodyParams": {
                type: "object",
            },
            "includeAdmin": {
                type: 'boolean'
            }, 
            "serviceName": {
                type: 'string'
            },
        },
    });
};
```

Comment: In fact, whatever I am putting in the `prefix' of the fastify-http-proxy, can see that prefix is flooding the swagger JSON and html. This line: `prefix: '/notifications',

Comment: I think `mystaging.com/` is usign `fastify.all` to define its routes. What do you expect as swagger output?

Comment: Only the ones which is inside notifications tag. Pit it another way, anything untagged (i.e. default), I want to avoid.

Comment: Could you add the `/notification/` route configuration?

Comment: Sure. I have added.
See I am currently working it around with the following settings in the fastify-swagger as ` hideUntagged: true`. 
But would like to know what is happening (to avoid any unintended consequences later on).